# Configure Comodo Internet Security to Allow Windows Sandbox to get internet

Tags: windows

I am using Comodo Internet Security, and want to get access to the internet on my Windows Sandbox. If I disable the Firewall in Comodo sandbox gets internet but it exposes my PC.

I have added WindowsSandbox.exe and WindowsSandboxClient.exe to the Firewall Applications rules and set them to allowed applications and also added them to HIPS Rules. But does not seem to work.

What am I missing? Please help with the configuration for the COMODO Internet Security setting to allow sandbox as an expection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason for Comodo blocking the Sandbox.

If Comodo was badly configured, it might be simpler to uninstall it,
install the latest version of Comodo and start configuring it again
from a clean state.
Keep testing the Sandbox to see exactly when it loses internet connection.

If this arrives again, Comodo might have a bug where it wrongly identifies
the Sandbox. This shouldn't have happened, since the Sandbox is a Windows
application that is digitally signed by Microsoft.
In this case, contact Comodo Support for help.

Comment: After I uninstall and reinstall the Comodo it works fine, but after some times it stops working again.

Comment: Contact Comodo Support for help. If you're modifying firewall rules, verify your changes. Note that Comodo does not improve substantially your security, as the firewall of your router and Windows Defender are quite enough.